# Regex: find character in block of text between quotes which may appear zero or more times

Tags: regex

Im trying to create a regex which can help parse a URL path within a CEF syslog message. My parser has trouble with un-escaped "=" within values and a more robust regex would fix it.

```
Shortened Sample:

<14>1 2022-12-16T12:07:15+00:00 HOSTNAME CEF:0|Palo Alto Networks|PAN-OS|9.4.1|Suspicious HTTP Evasion Found|THREAT|1|rt=Dec 16 2022 12:07:15 GMT deviceExternalId=000000000 request="browser.events.data.msn.com/OneCollector/1.0?cors=true&content" cs2Label=URL Category cs2=internet-portals
```

The "request" key typically contains the path and it can contain 0 or more "=".

I haven't seen any examples yet, but I think a fair assumption would be that any number of other fields could contain a similar string and the regex should be able to handle it.

GOAL: Identify all "=" inside any value wrapped in quotes

My regex-foo isn't great, I can capture up to 1 "=", but trying to expand any more either breaks captures, or it captures more than required.

```
Pattern: \".*(=).*\"
Captures only one instance inside one value, not great if there are more than 1 "=" or more keys which contain quoted strings with "=" inside.

MATCHES (find ** for match):
<14>1 2022-12-16T12:07:15+00:00 HOSTNAME CEF:0|Palo Alto Networks|PAN-OS|9.4.1|Suspicious HTTP Evasion Found|THREAT|1|rt=Dec 16 2022 12:07:15 GMT deviceExternalId=000000000 request="browser.events.data.msn.com/OneCollector/1.0?cors**=**true&content" cs2Label=URL Category cs2=internet-portals

FAILS (find ** for match, note there are 2 "="):
<14>1 2022-12-16T12:07:15+00:00 HOSTNAME CEF:0|Palo Alto Networks|PAN-OS|9.4.1|Suspicious HTTP Evasion Found|THREAT|1|rt=Dec 16 2022 12:07:15 GMT deviceExternalId=000000000 request="browser.events.data.msn.com/OneCollector/1.0?cors=true&content**=**" cs2Label=URL Category cs2=internet-portals

EXPECTED (find ** for match):
<14>1 2022-12-16T12:07:15+00:00 HOSTNAME CEF:0|Palo Alto Networks|PAN-OS|9.4.1|Suspicious HTTP Evasion Found|THREAT|1|rt=Dec 16 2022 12:07:15 GMT deviceExternalId=000000000 request="browser.events.data.msn.com/OneCollector/1.0?cors**=**true&content**=**" cs2Label=URL Category cs2=internet-portals
```

Comment: In which environment are you going to run the regex, and what do you want to do with the matched `=` sign?

Comment: You may be able do that with one expression, by looking ahead to make sure only balanced quotes remain in the string, if any, outside the quotes you match the `=`s in, for example via `=(?=[^"]*"(?:"[^"]+"|[^"]+)*+$)` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/wimYzK/1), requires PCRE or equivalent regex flavour that supports lookaheads and atomic grouping), but there may be easier multi-step approaches depending on the environment you want to achieve this in.